# RegExp for cyrillic and latin alphanumeric strings in ignite 2013.2 igTextEditor`s validatorOptions

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

In ignite-ui igTextEditor regexp validation for latin alphanumeric I tried :

```
regExp: /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

It works for latin alphanumeric but when it comes to regexp for both latin and cyrillic alphanumeric there is nothing that I can make to work.

What is the regexp that I must type in the validator options so that both latin and cyrillc strings are checked for alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cover the Cyrillic characters as a Unicode range:

```
regExp: /^[A-Za-z0-9\u0410-\u044F]+$/
```